# Having a difficulty with neo4j connection

Tags: neo4j, connection, bolt

I'm having a problem connecting to neo4j on a machine that previously didn't have any problems.

I've purged the previous installation from the machine and performed a new install - although I noticed that once activated it appeared to have a record of my previous activity.

Now, when connecting to the Desktop console, I'm getting conflicting messages on the one hand, :server connect returns

```
You are connected as user neo4j
to bolt://localhost:11001
Connection credentials are stored in your web browser.
```

On the other hand, any Cypher code I try to enter returns:

```
BoltConnectionError
BoltConnectionError: No connection found, did you connect to Neo4j?
 BoltConnectionError: No connection found, did you connect to Neo4j?
:server connect
Connect to Neo4j
Database access requires an authenticated connection.
```

How can it be both?

Comment: Using the built in browser of the Neo4j desktop, I've observed the same error scenario. It happened to me, when I executed a long-running query in the background (`CALL apoc.periodic.iterate([...]`) for multiple hours). It seems the Neo4j browser is able to make only one connection to the database. Each further executed query resulted in your „No connection found, did you connect to Neo4j?“ message. But the restriction seems to be limited to the Neo4j Desktop only. From your app you can set up additional connections to the same Neo4j server nevertheless.

Comment: Ok, if it can only manage one connection at a time, perhaps the fact that I activated the desktop and consulted localhost:7474 at the same time created the problem ?